# Hazelcast absolute expiration of items

Tags: hazelcast

I am using Hazelcast "3.6.3" on scala 2.11.8

I have written this code.

```
val config = new Config("mycluster")
config.getNetworkConfig.getJoin.getMultcastConfig.setEnabled(false)
config.getNetworkConfig.getJoin.getMulticastConfig.setEnabled(false)
config.getNetworkConfig.getJoin.getAwsConfig.setEnabled(false)
config.getNetworkConfig.getJoin.getTcpIpConfig.setMembers(...)
config.getNetworkConfig.getJoin.getTcpIpConfig.setEnabled(true)
val hc = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config)
hc.getConfig.addMapConfig(new MapConfig()
     .setName("foo")
     .setBackupCount(1)
     .setTimeToLiveSeconds(3600)
     .setAsyncBackupCount(1)
     .setInMemoryFormat(InMemoryFormat.BINARY)
     .setMaxSizeConfig(new MaxSizeConfig(1, MaxSizePolicy.USED_HEAP_SIZE))
)
hc.putValue[(String, Int)]("foo", "1", ("foo", 10))
```

I notice that when 1 hour is over hazelcast does not remove the items from the cache. The items seem to be living forever in the cache.

I don't want sliding expiration. I want absolute expiration this means that after 1 hour the item has to be kicked out no matter how many times it was accessed during the hour.

I have done required googling and I think my code above is correct. But when I look at my server logs, I am pretty sure that nothing is removed from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am not a scala guy. But can you explain what does hc.addTimeToLiveMapConfig does? 
Normally you need to add the TTL config into Config object before starting Hazelcast.

I believe in your case, you are starting Hazelcast and only then updating the config with TTL. Please try with reverse order. 
If you don't like to add this to the configuration, there is an overloaded map.put method that takes TTL as an input. This way you can specify TTL per entry.

Comment: Ok, just change the order of setting the config and starting the node. What you are trying to do is not supported by Hazelcast atm. You are updating the config after you have started the node.

Comment: config.addMapConfig(new MapConfig() .... should be before val hc = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config)

Comment: I got a down vote on my answer. Not sure why. Did this change solved your problem?